# Подскажите что не так в этой проверке на семну префикса python

Tags: python, discord.py

Смотрите у меня есть код на смену префикса
Он работает
Но я сделал проверку если участник не укажет префикс то ему напишет чтобы он указал префикс
Но бот после того как я написал команду n.prefix
Написал что надо указать префикс
И тут же написал что префикс успешно изменён на None
И команды перестали работать

Вот код:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def prefix(ctx, prefix):
    if prefix is None:
        await ctx.send('Укажите префикс')
        else:
            global custom_prefixes
            with open("pr.json", "r+") as f:
              custom_prefixes = json.load(f)
              if ctx.guild.id in custom_prefixes:
                      if custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id] != prefix:
                        del custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id]
                        custom_prefixes.update({str(ctx.guild.id):prefix})
                        with open("pr.json", "w") as f:
                            json.dump(custom_prefixes, f)
                            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = ' | Префикс', description = f'✅ Вы успешно изменили префикс на: `{prefix}`.', color = emb_color))
```

Comment: Ну так, ваша функция ничего не возвращает, значит будет None

Answer (score 0):

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def prefix(self, ctx, prefix=None):
    if not prefix:
        return await ctx.send('Укажите префикс')

    global custom_prefixes
    with open("pr.json", "r+") as f:
        custom_prefixes = json.load(f)
        if ctx.guild.id in custom_prefixes:
                if custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id] != prefix:
                del custom_prefixes[ctx.guild.id]
                custom_prefixes.update({str(ctx.guild.id):prefix})
                with open("pr.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(custom_prefixes, f)
                    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = ' | Префикс', description = f'✅ Вы успешно изменили префикс на: `{prefix}`.', color = emb_color))
```

Comment: Не работает((((

Comment: Конкретнее можно? У вас коги? Проверьте ещё раз.

Comment: Нет не коги уллу